# importing a state value from react class component

Tags: reactjs

In my App.js I have this state object:

*App.js*

```
this.state = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        Authorization:
            "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianR}
};
```

I want to export this.state.headers to my globalMethods.js file, which has a data posting function:

*globalMethods.js*

```
export function submitUserData() {
    fetch("http://dev.test.lt/be/api/user/data", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers // <-- this exact variable has to be this.state.headers
    })
        .then(response => response.json())

}
```

Can't export headers from App.js, since `export const headers = this.state.headers` cannot access "this" scope.

Exports within App class are, of course, not possible.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variable when you are calling the `submitUserData.js`.

```
callingUrl = () => {
  const response = submitUserData(this.state.headers)
}
```

So your function should be like this...

```
export function submitUserData(customHeaders) {
    fetch("http://dev.test.lt/be/api/user/data", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: customHeaders
    })
        .then(response => response.json())

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is global state analog.
So my advice would be to create some plain js module named `requestHelper.js` with property

```
export const requestHeaders = headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",}
```

and exporting method `setHeader(name, value)`

import that method into your app component, and call it on auth request success. Later get  your headers from `requestHelper.requestHeaders` object anywhere in your app

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind external intermediate container to do that. E. g. you can make your component save headers to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for that.
Or do it backwards: export your headers from `globalMethods.js` and use it inside class.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
    import React from "react"

    const header ={};
    class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            Authorization:
                "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianR}
    };
    }
      render() {
header = this.state.headers
return   <div/>
      }
    }


export header
```